# How to get into terminal on my Dell laptop which interferes with Wi-Fi button?

Tags: 10.04, dell, gnome-terminal

I use 10.04  regularly and I dual-booted my laptop with 10.04 and Windows 7 already.

I  made a mistake in deleting my entire top and bottom panel on 10.04. So I am trying to get it back.

When I search through forums, it asks me to go to terminal and use some commands to get it back. But the problem is, I am not able to access my terminal through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, my Wi-Fi goes off because it is the Wi-Fi button on my Dell laptop and my Internet is off. It doesn't bring me a terminal. How should I get to a terminal to do any further action?

---

@obsessive foss  Thank you..That helped CTRl+Alt+T. I just pressed some commands  to get back my ubuntu top panel. I used the commands

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown

rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel

pkill gnome-panel
```

But the cursory look at commands suggests i am shutting down gconftool and then killing process gnome panel too. How am i able to get back my top panel then..what are these commands actually doing??

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted with the checkmark to the left of it. Also, please move the question about the commands into a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> as the function keys may need <kbd>Fn</kbd>. However, tris lets you run one command and the better key combination to use is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

This actually applies to cases where any function key(<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>) acts improperly.